# Trying to filter geoJSON data using the $.getJSON function

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, geojson, getjson

I'm trying to filter geoJSON data using the $.getJSON function, but I'm stuck on how to filter the data to what I want and then applying that to the geojson = data.

Here is the code below:

```
// Fetch the GeoJSON file

$.getJSON(config.geojson, function (data) {
  geojson = data
  features = $.map(geojson.features, function(feature) {
    return feature.properties;
  });
  featureLayer.addData(data);
  buildConfig();
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Also note that you can feel free to use ordinary JS to make network requests and use array methods, you don't need a library

Comment: `I'm stuck on how to filter the data to what I want` - that's where i'm stuck too since you didn't provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: I was just looking for a generic answer, but I'm wanting to filter to a certain feature.properties (example: contractor = 'Tilson') and then apply that to the geojson = data, as that's where the rest of my code is getting the geojson data from is at that point.

Answer (score 0):

To filter your features according to a specific property (such as contractor === 'Tilson'), use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on it:

```
geojson = data.features.filter(function(feature) {
    return feature.properties.contractor === 'Tilson';
});
```

Comment: Can I add an IF Statement in that?

Comment: Also would that affect this:   featureLayer.addData(data);

Comment: - No, `filter` does not mutate the array `data`. You could store this result in a `filteredData` variable and use it instead of `data` both times.
 - You certainly can use an if statement. You just need to return a truthy value for items you want to keep.